# Can not scroll recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I am trying to implement a Recyclerview but I just can not make it scrollable. I read several threads here in StackOverflow, but I was not able to find one to fix my problem. I think there is something related to the MapView because I have another similar activity without maps that I can scroll, but I still do not know how to fix in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activities.BookmarkActivity">

  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/bk_mapView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent" app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/bk_linearlayout" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_mapView">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/radlabel" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="25dp" android:layout_marginStart="4dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:hint="@string/bk_radiusName" android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="15sp" android:textStyle="bold" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bk_textName" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/bk_seekBar" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:max="1000" android:min="10" android:progress="50" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bk_imageButton"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radlabel" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/bk_imageButton" android:layout_width="25dp" android:layout_height="25dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/bk_textName" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginStart="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:hint="@string/bk_bookmarkName" android:inputType="textCapWords"
      android:maxLength="30" android:textSize="15sp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bk_notify" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_seekBar" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/bk_notifyWifiOnly" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="WifiOnly" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_marginEnd="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_textName" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_seekBar" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/bk_notify" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Notify" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_marginEnd="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_textName"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bk_notifyWifiOnly" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_seekBar" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/emptyFrameLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_linearlayout">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginStart="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:textAlignment="center" android:layout_marginBottom="150dp" android:textSize="20sp" android:textStyle="bold|italic"
      android:text="None Here" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </FrameLayout>


  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/topFrameLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginEnd="2dp" android:visibility="visible" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_linearlayout">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout android:id="@+id/bk_swipeRefreshLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/bk_recycler_view" app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

  </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The actual layout screenshot is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView`. The `SwipeRefreshLayout` extends `ViewGroup` and is used to allow the user to refresh/update the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture. It can, therefore, detect vertical swipe gestures made by the users, but it in and off itself does not behave as a scroll view.

Your code should be converted to something along the following lines:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bk_linearlayout">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/bk_swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/bk_recycler_view"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            </ScrollView>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

To get a basic idea on how to use `SwipeRefreshLayout`, refer to this [article](https://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/). Also, refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout).

**Summary about SwipeRefreshLayout (from official documentation)**

> The SwipeRefreshLayout should be used whenever the user can refresh the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture. The activity that instantiates this view should add an OnRefreshListener to be notified whenever the swipe to refresh gesture is completed. The SwipeRefreshLayout will notify the listener each and every time the gesture is completed again; the listener is responsible for correctly determining when to actually initiate a refresh of its content. If the listener determines there should not be a refresh, it must call setRefreshing(false) to cancel any visual indication of a refresh. If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should call setRefreshing(true). To disable the gesture and progress animation, call setEnabled(false) on the view.
>
> This layout should be made the parent of the view that will be refreshed as a result of the gesture and can only support one direct child. This view will also be made the target of the gesture and will be forced to match both the width and the height supplied in this layout. The SwipeRefreshLayout does not provide accessibility events; instead, a menu item must be provided to allow refresh of the content wherever this gesture is used.

Comment: I tried that , tks! But unfortunatelly it did not work. Also tried to use NestedScrollView , but still it did not work.